# java scripta dialog box 2 windows

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this code to create two separated dialog boxes, but when I add the code for second it appears only if first appears.This is the code of the first:

```
    function showPopUp(el) {
        var cvr = document.getElementById("cover")
        var dlg = document.getElementById(el)
        cvr.style.display = "block"
        dlg.style.display = "block"
        if (document.body.style.overflow = "hidden") {
            cvr.style.width = "1024"
            cvr.style.height = "100%"
        }
    }
    function closePopUp(el) {
        var cvr = document.getElementById("cover")
        var dlg = document.getElementById(el)
        cvr.style.display = "none"
        dlg.style.display = "none"
        document.body.style.overflowY = "scroll"
    }
```

This is the code of the second:

```
    function showPopUp2(e12) {
        var cvr = document.getElementById("cover2")
        var dlg = document.getElementById(el2)
        cvr.style.display = "block"
        dlg.style.display = "block"
        if (document.body.style.overflow = "hidden") {
            cvr.style.width = "1024"
            cvr.style.height = "100%"
        }
    }
    function closePopUp1(el2) {
        var cvr = document.getElementById("cover2")
        var dlg = document.getElementById(el2)
        cvr.style.display = "none"
        dlg.style.display = "none"
        document.body.style.overflowY = "scroll"
    }
```

Can someone help on this ?

Comment: Please learn the difference between JavaScript (yes) and Java (no).

Comment: `e12` or `el2` ? See your script of second popup

Comment: i think that would be a matter

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi +1 for eagle eyes

Answer (score 0):

Your `IF` conditionals are wrong. You've got

```
if (document.body.style.overflow = "hidden") {
```

It should be

```
if (document.body.style.overflow == "hidden") {
                                  ^ see here.
```

You could also use strict compare (`===`)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out :

```
function showPopUp2(e12) { // its e12
    var cvr = document.getElementById("cover2")
    var dlg = document.getElementById(el2)// but you call el2 here
    cvr.style.display = "block"
    dlg.style.display = "block"
    if (document.body.style.overflow = "hidden") {
        cvr.style.width = "1024"
        cvr.style.height = "100%"
    }
}
```

Try to fix it. Hope it helps.. :)